# Randomly Generating Exam Questions. Numbers based on Number + Letter associated with Questions

Tags: python

I have about 10 individual exams to go through. Each exam has a title containing a month and a year. In each exam, I have selected questions which have a number assigned to them that I find relevant for my work. Furthermore, each question number has a learning outcome assigned to it, which a numeric value plus a letter.

There are 25 possible learning outcomes assigned to each question. I currently have the data stored in an Excel document, like so:

[image]

**Here is the main problem**: I would like to randomly generate questions which have unique learning outcomes so that I can create an exam of 25 questions. In generating the questions, I would like to have the question number and the exam that it comes from.

I don't know Python well enough, unfortunately, to think of a way to do this quickly for my work, but my first thought is perhaps to create a dictionary of question numbers associated with the learning outcomes for each exam, and then put each exam dictionary into a larger dictionary (if that's even such a thing). However, I'm not sure how I could use anything with a random functionality on dictionaries.

Comment: where are the questions coming from?

Comment: So the "unique learning outcomes" are 1a..1e, 2a..2e, ... 5a..5e? And you want to generate "exams" which are unique vectors of outcomes?

Comment: without more info it is basically impossible to give a worthwhile answer

Comment: @HughBothwell, the learning outcomes are 1a-e, 2a-c, 3a-d, 4a-h, 5a-e.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham - I'm not sure how much more clear I could be. From reading the answer below, it seems that at least one person understands what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're on the right track by adding questions to dictionaries. Here's how I would approach this.

First, populate a dictionary. The keys of the dictionary are the learning objectives, and the values are lists of questions that meet those learning objectives.

```
# Assumption: question_list has tuples (<question_no>,<learning_obj>,<exam_date>)
learning_dict = {}
for question in question_list:
  question_no = question[0]
  learning_obj = question[1]
  if learning_obj in learning_dict:
    learning_dict[learning_obj].append(question_no)
  else:
    learning_dict[learning_obj] = [question_no]
```

Now you want to get exactly one question from each learning objective, right? You can use `random.choice` for this, while iterating over the dictionary's items.

```
import random

final_question_list = []
for learning_obj, question_list in learning_dict.items():
  random_question = random.choice(question_list)
  final_question_list.append(random_question)
```

And at the end of this, `final_question_list` will have one randomly-chosen question for each learning objective.

Comment: I will try out your code after I transfer all of these values out of Excel. Thank you for your help!

Comment: This *almost* gives me what I want. Only one problem: the same question number may be used more than once. So for example, as above, I chose #1 from the May 2007 exam. I could also choose #1 from November 2007 as well. (I do realize this is my fault for not explaining that.)

Comment: Never mind - I figured it out! It only required a few modifications! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your spreadsheet has a fourth column containing the question text:

Save your spreadsheet as a .csv file, then

```
from collections import defaultdict
import csv

outcomes = set()
questions_by_outcome = defaultdict(list)

# load questions from csv
with open("myspreadsheet.csv", "rb") as inf:
    for row in csv.reader(inf):
        q_num, outcome, exam, q_text = row     # unpack row items
        outcomes.add(outcome)
        questions_by_outcome[outcome].append((exam, q_num, q_text))
```

Your data is now in Python in a format like:

```
outcomes = {"2a", "4b", "1d", "2c"}    # set of unique outcome codes

questions_by_outcome = {
    "1d": [
        ("May 2007", "16", "What does abc def?"),
        ("May 2010", "14", "Who did xyz?")
    ],
    "4b": [
        ("May 2007", "4", "What is the airspeed velocity of an unladen swallow?"),
        ("Nov 2004", "6", "Do you by chance have any Gruyere?")
    ]
}
```

Now to pick a random question per outcome:

```
import random

# randomize the order of outcomes
outcomes = list(outcomes)
random.shuffle(outcomes)

# pick a random question per outcome
my_questions = [(outcome,) + random.choice(questions_by_outcome[outcome]) for outcome in outcomes]
```

which leaves you with a list containing one question per outcome, like

```
my_questions = [
    # outcome, exam, q_num, q_text
    ("4b", "May 2007", "4", "What is the airspeed velocity of an unladen swallow?"),
    ("1d", "May 2010", "14", "Who did xyz?")
]
```

Hope that helps.